# Should I use AND or BUT?

Tags: conjunctions

Should one answer the question "Do you have any brothers or sisters?" saying "I have one brother AND no sisters." or "I have one brother BUT no sisters."?

Comment: Both are fine. It's just a very slight shift in nuance / emphasis whether to call attention to the contrast between the existence of brothers and the absence of sisters.

Comment: Note that if the question had been *"Who else lives in your house besides you and your parents?*, it might be just about okay to use ***but,*** but really weird to use ***and*** in the reply *There's one brother and two sisters **and** no dog*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are fine.  You can view the second clause (I have no sisters) as being in addition to the first one, or in contrast with the first one.  So both "and" and "but" are reasonable choices for the conjunction.

In a normal colloquial conversation, I would choose to emphasise the contrast and use "but".

Comment: I think most native speakers would just answer "I have one brother"; you don't need to specify "and/but no sisters."